sorting behavior and sorting sequence for mongodb
Does MongoDB use a different sort sequence order when sorting within a $search operation compared to a normal sort operation?
case 1:
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $search: {
      index: "default_multi_sort",
      compound: {
        must: [
          {
            in: {
              path: "_id",
              value: [
               ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafca"),
               ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafcf"),
               ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafcd"),
               ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafce"),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      sort: {
        name: 1,
      },
    },
  }], {
            collation: {
                locale: "en",
                numericOrdering: true
            }
        })

case 2:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match:
      {
        _id: {
          $in: [
            ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafca"),
            ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafcf"),
            ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafcd"),
            ObjectId("636cf2849d8e183db53aafce"),
          ],
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      name: 1,
    },
  },
], {
  collation: {
    locale: "en",
    numericOrdering: true
  }
});

In the first case, I receive numbers followed by alphabets, while in the second case, I receive a special character, then numbers, and finally alphabets. If this is true, how can I make them behave the same way?
below is my search index definition:
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "fields": {
      "name": [
            {
              "tokenization": "nGram",
              "type": "autocomplete",
              "analyzer": "lucene.keyword"
            },
            {
              "type": "token"
            }
          ],
        }
}

}

In case 2, what is the pipeline [{ { name: 1, }, }] ? Did you forget to put the stage operation $sort ?

Also, you case 2 doesn't have any match criteria so all documents are returned. So case 1 also probably returns special characters first but your compound query doesn't have them in the results at all, so no symbols to sort. Do symbols appear at the end for case 1?

@aneroid, I have updated the question.
